# Conditional CSS to display title on Blog only

Tags: css, wordpress, hide, title, codex

I'm trying to hide the page title on ALL pages, except the Blog Roll.

If I make the following changes to the style.css, it will hide the title on all pages, including the blog roll:

```
h1 {
    Display:none;
    font-size: 48px;
    margin: 33px 0;
}
```

and

```
.entry-title {
     Display:none;
     font-weight: normal;
     margin: 0 0 5px;
}
```

---

According to http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#Testing_for_sub-Pages, in order to single out the Blog Roll, I need to use the following condition:

```
if ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) {
  // Default homepage
} elseif ( is_front_page() ) {
  // static homepage
} elseif ( is_home() ) {
  // blog page
} else {
  //everyting else
}
```

So, I apply these conditions, to my code, where the changes successfully worked initially, however it simply does not work. The titles change size and shape, but are still visiable on ALL pages.

Revised code:

```
h1 {
    if ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) {
        Display:none;
        font-size: 48px;
        margin: 33px 0;
    } elseif ( is_front_page() ) {
        Display:none;
        font-size: 48px;
        margin: 33px 0;
    } elseif ( is_home() ) {
        font-size: 48px;
        margin: 33px 0;
    } else {
        Display:none;
        font-size: 48px;
        margin: 33px 0;
    }
}
```

And ..

```
.entry-title {
    if ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) {
        Display:none;
        font-weight: normal;
        margin: 0 0 5px;
    } elseif ( is_front_page() ) {
        Display:none;
        font-weight: normal;
        margin: 0 0 5px;
    } elseif ( is_home() ) {
        font-weight: normal;
        margin: 0 0 5px;
    } else {
        Display:none;
        font-weight: normal;
        margin: 0 0 5px;
    }
}
```

Can I not use `Display:none;` in a conditional statement or something?

Comment: Did Wordpress state that you need to paste PHP script in CSS?

Comment: Wait, these are PHP scripts? SHEESH! Back to the drawing board. Thanks.

Comment: I have such a minimal grasp on CSS, PHP, HTML, I saw the code making some sort of changes to the look of the site, which is why I assumed I was on the right track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from what i understand, you need to remove title only from blog page. the easiest way to do this with css is

```
.blog .entry-title{display:none}
```

where .blog is the class name of your blog page body. (you can get the body class name by inspecting elements.)

Comment: is .blog a standard class name across every Wordpress theme? Also, I'm looking for the reverse effect, I only want the page title on the blog roll, and hidden on all other pages.

Comment: no.its depends on the theme. do one thing, open your site in chrome and right click. click on "inspect element" then at the top of all elements you can see the classes of your current page.
something like this <body class="page page-id-13 page-template-default custom-background">

Comment: to reverse the effects,
.entry-title{display:none}
.blog .entry-title{display:block}

Comment: This worked perfectly, I had no idea there was a .blog class (Again, my CSS knowledge is severely lacking.) Thank you!